# How do I query a column from a parent table in the children's table using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, parent and children, I need to query one column from parent table and all columns from children's table using sqlalchemy.

My tables:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from sqlalchemy import (TIMESTAMP, Column, Float, ForeignKey, Integer, String)
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Date
from database import db

@dataclass
class Children(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'children'

  id_children: int
  id_parent: int
  children_start_date: Date
  children_end_date: Date

  id_children= Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  id_parent = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parent.id_parent"), nullable=True)
  children_start_date= Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)
  children_end_date= Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)

@dataclass
class Parent(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'parent'

  id_parent: int
  parent_start_date: Date
  parent_end_date: Date
  parent_code: str
  children: Children

  id_parent= Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  parent_start_date= Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)
  parent_end_date= Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)
  parent_code = Column(String(500), nullable=True)

  children= db.relationship(
      "Children",
      lazy='noload',
      primaryjoin="Parent.id_parent == Children.id_parent"
  )
```

And then the query, with session, where I need to get all children columns and only parent_code from parent:

```
 from datetime import datetime
 from database import db
 from . import models

 start_time = request.args.get('startTime')
 end_time = request.args.get('endTime')

 start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
 end_time = datetime.strptime(end_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

 record = db.session.query(models.Children, models.Parent.parent_code).filter(
      models.Children.children_start_date.between(start_time, end_time),
  ).join(models.Parent,
         models.Parent.id_parent== models.Children.id_parent).all()
```

But this returns in the following format:

```
[
 [
  0: Children dict
  1: parent_code
 ]
]
```

If a make a dict mapping:

```
record = [dict(zip(u.keys(), u)) for u in record]
```

It returns:

```
[
 [
  Children: Children dict
  parent_code: parent_code
 ]
]
```

But I want in this format:

```
[
 {
  Children dict,
  parent_code
 }
]
```

Someone knows how to put in this format? Preferably in the query (db.session.query), it can be in the select, join, or somenthing else, I would not like to make some other mapping after the query.
Or, if someone know another way to make ths query with sqlalchemy.